# Как удалить таблицу SQlite?

Tags: java, android, sql, sqlite

"DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT  не удаляет старую таблицу. Что не так сделано?

```
 public class DBHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper {
        public static final String TABLE_CONTACT = "autowash";
        public static final String COLUMN_LATLNG = "latlng";
        public static final String COLUMN_ID = "id";
        public static final String COLUMN_NAME = "name";
        public static final String COLUMN_SITY = "sity";
        public static final String COLUMN_ADRESS = "adr";
        public static final String COLUMN_PHONE = "phone";
        public static final String COLUMN_BEGIN = "begin";
        public static final String COLUMN_ENDING = "ending";

        private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "autowash.db";
        private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 2;

        // Database creation sql statement
        private static final String DATABASE_CREATE =
                "CREATE TABLE " + TABLE_CONTACT
                        + "("
                        + COLUMN_ID + " INTEGER PRIMARY KEY, "
                        + COLUMN_NAME + " TEXT, "
                        + COLUMN_SITY + " TEXT, "
                        + COLUMN_LATLNG + " REAL, "
                        + COLUMN_ADRESS + " TEXT, "
                        + COLUMN_PHONE  + " TEXT, "
                        + COLUMN_BEGIN  + " TEXT, "
                        + COLUMN_ENDING + " TEXT  "
                        + ");";


        public DBHelper(Context context) {
            super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);
        }

        @Override
        public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase database) {
            database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
        }

        @Override
        public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion) {
            if (newVersion > oldVersion) {
                db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT);
                onCreate(db);
           }
        }
    }
```

Comment: До этого DATABASE_VERSION  была равна 1?

Comment: А у вас точно условие `newVersion > oldVersion` выполняется?

Comment: Да,  DATABASE_VERSION была равна 1

Comment: Данные в БД берутся из JSON(которые меняется постоянно) c сервера. Т.е. БД всегда имеет новую версию при входе в приложение.

Comment: @P.Dm Я вот смотрю ваш код и вижу, что у вас версия БД всегда 2

Comment: if (newVersion > oldVersion)  условие будет выполняться, когда вы обновляете приложение.

Comment: т.е условие лишнее?

Answer (score 2):

Уверены ли вы в том, что эта строчка выполняется?

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT);
```

После выполнения этого запроса таблица должна дропнуться.
После у вас выполняется код:

```
onCreate(db);
```

из которого выполняется

```
database.execSQL(DATABASE_CREATE);
```

а значит таблица создаётся снова

в метод **onUpgrade** вы попадаете в случае если версия дб изменилась т.е. **DATABASE_VERSION**
а условие

```
if (newVersion > oldVersion)
```

Необходимо для уточнения версии (если вы например будете поддерживать приложение в котором будут часто меняться версии бд и информацию из них необходимо будет сохранять.

Попробуйте продебажить и поставьте бреакпоинт на строчке

```
db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT);
```

Должно получится так -
если изменить при том коде который вы предоставили **DATABASE_VERSION** на 3, то после включения приложения вы получите **autowash.db** с пустой таблицей **autowash**.

Comment: Пока я решил свою проблему удалением БД при открытие приложения и созданием новой с изменениями.

Answer (score 0):

а может такой запрос пройдет:

```
IF OBJECT_ID('TableName', 'U') IS NOT NULL
DROP TABLE TableName;
```

?

Comment: Речь идёт о Sqlite, не о Sql Server.

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего, в процессе проектирования, вы изменили название таблицы на более понятное. У таблицы в установленном приложении осталось старое название.

Соответственно `db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + TABLE_CONTACT);` ее не находит по новому имени.